# How to load jar files when running javac to compile Java class which imports some libraries?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jar, javac

Below is the structure of my very basic sample Spring framework application.

```
libs/
   com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
   com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar
   jmxtools-1.2.1.jar
   org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
   org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
   org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
   org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
   org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
Test.java
```

Below is the sample Java class `Test.java` which import some Spring Framework libaries.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  

        Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");  
        student.displayInfo();  
    }  
}
```

When I try to compile this `Test` Java class by running this command `javac -d . Test.java`, I get the following errors:

```
 error: package org.springframework.beans.factory does not exist
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

 error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml does not exist 
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;

 error: package org.springframework.core.io does not exist
 import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

 error: package org.springframework.core.io does not exist
 import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
```

I think this is because I did not load the Spring framework jar files in the `libs` directory. When I run the following command, it kind of solves one error:

```
javac -cp libs/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar -d . Test.java
```

If I run `javac -cp libs/*.jar -d . Test.java`, I get the following errors:

```
error: invalid flag: libs/[EACH JAR FILE].jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

How do I load (multiple) jar files when trying to compile Java class with `javac`?

Comment: try libs/* instead of "*.jar"

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple jar files inside a directory and you want to compile a java class, you can do it in the following manner.

```
javac -classpath lib/* <path to java file>/YourJavaFile.java
```

In my case, I tried like this and it is working fine for me.

```
javac -classpath lib/* E:/kafka-dev-2019/kafkaexample/src/main/java/com/devglan/kafka/Consumer.java
```

In this case, there is no need to mention each and every jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are different ways to mention the `<path-to-jar>` and it is dependent on the OS.
For **Mac** you have to mention it in `double quotes "<path-to-jar>"`

> javac -cp "libs/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar" -d .
>   Test.java

or you can use -classpath

> javac -classpath "libs/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"
>   -d . Test.java

For **Ubuntu**, you have to use `semi colon <path-to-jar>;`

> javac -cp libs/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar; -d .
>   Test.java

Instead, you can add all **dependency jar files** in the **environment variables** to save yourself from the redundant task of mentioning it every time.